# how to know that wifi supports only ipv6 i.e it is ipv6 only router

Tags: wifi, ipv6

How can Wifi router clients can know that router supports ipv6 only and does not support ipv4 ?.

We currently use a faulty logic that if router does not provide ipv4 ip .
consider it as ipv6 only router .

but this can cause problem in case of some ipv4 dhcp server issue in router .

can supplicant or other module can know that it is ipv6 only router ?.

is there any android api to know this .

Comment: This looks like an [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/66377/189912). What is the real underlying problem you are trying to solve with IPv6-only detection?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The clients can't know if the router only provides IPv6 or if router has an ipv4-failure.

Smart clients could check if DNS is DNS64. In that case the probability is high, that the router doesn't provide IPv4.

There is a draft on going to do it via flag in the RAs.

https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/draft-ietf-6man-ipv6only-flag-02

Comment: how can wifi clients check that router has dns64 ?.

Comment: By asking an AAAA-Record for an IPv4-only hostname.

Answer (score 2):

There are so many combinations and edge cases that it is usually a bad idea to manually deal with this. Even if you only have an IPv6 address you can have connectivity using 464xlat for example. The best solution is to make connections using hostnames and let the operating system deal with the complexities.

Comment: For 464xlat the client knows already that the connection is IPv6-only. He has to guess the relevant NAT64-prefix and to use a second IPv6-address for mapping the IPv4-requests.